# Returning an int value from Find Max method & printing that in test file

Tags: c++, return-value

Ive implemented a findMax method & a tester to test this function. Beforehand, I had the findMax method as void, and simply had cout << maxValue << at the end of the method, so that when it was called in the main tester, it printed out the result I wanted.

I'm trying to change that so the return type of the method is int, and in the main being able to print out the value being returned by the method. When i try manipulate the variable maxValue in the tester file, it says variable undefined.

What do I do to fix this? And also what is the most appropriate way to do this? having the method as a void type and having the cout statement within the method or having it as a integer type so that it returns an int at the end??

Thanks.

```
#ifndef FINDMAX_H
#define FINDMAX_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template < typename T >
int FindMax(T* array, int array_len) {

    if (!array || array_len  <=0 ) {
        cout << "Invalid Array" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

        //T * newArray = new int[array_len]; //create new array
        T maxValue = array[0]; //set to the first array element
        int largestIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < array_len; i++) { //going through array from pos 2
            if (array[i] > maxValue) { //checking if value at array position i is > maxValue
                maxValue = array[i]; //set maxValue = to element at current Array position
                largestIndex = i; //set largest index = to the current index it is at
            }

            return maxValue;
        }
        //cout << "The max value in this array is: " << maxValue << endl;//return highest value in array

        //cout << "The max value is at position : " << largestIndex << endl;//return position of highest value in the array
        //cout << "" << endl;
}

#endif
```

Tester

```
#include "FindMax.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>

int main() {


    int array_len = 10; 
    int* array = new int[array_len];
    double* array2 = new double[array_len];

    for (int i = 0; i < array_len; i++) //fill array 1
        array[i] = i * i;

    for (int i = 0; i < array_len; i++) //fill array 2
        array2[i] = i * 2.5;

    FindMax(array, array_len);
    cout << maxValue << endl; // error here


}
```

Comment: you have two return statements in the same control flow?

Comment: it you want to return both maxValue and largestIndex .. you should look up `struct` as a option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the function has unreachable code

```
template < typename T >
int FindMax(T* array, int array_len) {
            //...

            return maxValue;
            return largestIndex;
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        }
        //cout << "The max value in this array is: " << maxValue << endl;//return highest value in array

        //cout << "The max value is at position : " << largestIndex << endl;//return position of highest value in the array
        //cout << "" << endl;
}
```

You should remove the last return statement.

As for the error then you should write

```
int maxValue = FindMax(array, array_len);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cout << maxValue << endl; // error here
```

that is you have to declare variable `maxValue` and assign it with the return value of the algorithm.

Comment: @LiamLaverty Yes. In main the name maxValue is unknown because it is not declared.

Comment: @LiamLaverty the scope of the variable maxValue in the algorithm is limited by the body of the algorithm. It is its local variable that is invisible and not alive outside the algorithm.

Comment: What method is better in order to print out the result? having a cout statement within the method itself, so that all you need to do is call the method in the main with the parameters, or having the cout in the main & giving the value of maxValue the value returned from the method?

Comment: @LiamLaverty It is better then a function does the main task it is designed for. For example imagine if you need to get the maximum and process it further without any message outputting. What will you do? Write a second function?:)

Comment: Cheers @Vlad from moscow!

Comment: whats the best way for me to return the largestIndex variable and print it out in the tester since the method cannot return 2 values?